# How can I prevent my title text from getting misaligned?

Tags: codenameone

When there's a back button in the Toolbar, the title text get centered in the remaining space which is useful in some cases. However, is there a way to disable this behavior? In my case, I'd like it to be centered absolutely relative to the entire Toolbar width so that the title is aligned with the subtitle. Currently, it looks like this which is ugly:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a behavior in the `Toolbar` we should probably set to default but have some concerns about. Use `toolbar.setTitleCentered(true)`.